# How to set item windowBackground in android resource file programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm working on a splash screen that pops up when launching the app, but instead of inflating a layout in the Activity, I want to set a theme specifically for the splash activity that has an image resource  in it.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

styles.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My question is:
Is it possible to change `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>` via code?
I receive a list of image urls from the network that should be set as a splash screen randomly, so the splash screen has to be dynamically set.
I've managed to find the following code but I just don't know how to proceed from there.

```kotlin
val styleId = resources.getIdentifier("SplashTheme", "style", packageName)
val drawableFromPath = Drawable.createFromPath("some image url")
```

Should I just use fragment instead?

Comment: if you're using a splash screen to display something received from the network then you're missing the actual purpose of the splash screen

Comment: Thanks for the feedback zedlabs! Is it because the purpose of the splash screen is to create an initial layout of the app while fetching the data? I should get the better way to present the images.

Comment: the purpose of the splash screen is to show something (mostly a static vector) to the user while the app loads the initial data, you can load the images as the initial data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zedlabs said, you might be getting the concept wrong. What you see by setting the following property is

```xml
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
```

You set what you see while the app is loading up. Usually it is a white screen but by replacing it you see what you set in instead. It is also the default `windowBackground` of all the app.

So if you intend to set it as dynamic, it won't really work as for you to fetch the resources app would need to be loaded up and by the time it loads up this screen won't be visible anymore.

You can opt for a custom Splash Screen that specifically displays for sometime and then the app launches.

I would suggest to check this out: https://medium.com/android-news/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll check on the link